# Binary Tree traversal maze

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, evolutionary-algorithm

I'm creating a binary tree maze. The tree has 8 leaves and the goal is to traverse the tree and find "food" at one or more of the leaves. At each node, the participant can either chose the left or right node to go to next. Or, it can traverse both, but at some cost (maybe 1 time step versus 2 by choosing on or the other). If it reaches a leaf with no food, it has to backtrack and remake its decision. This is eventually going to turn into an evolutionary algorithm where the strategies are stored and evolved over multiple generations. What is the most efficient way to store the path traversed (so the participant may backtrack if food is not found)?

Comment: Define efficient. Do you mean CPU cycles (if so, what operations are you planning), or memory?

Comment: Sorry, i mean efficient in lines of code. really i just need some sort of way to remember the traversal

Comment: You can leave bread crumbs at each node, or you can keep a list of nodes visited. Still not sure about your definition of efficiency, but either of those methods will get the job done. The big difference is with bread crumbs, you can only have one path at a time. With lists, you can keep track of multiple paths, if that's desirable.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to approach this. One thing that comes to mind is to have a boolean flag at each node, and if the node is visited return and store the node's index or key value in this array.

Example:

```
1. Start tree traversal
 2. User picks direction(right/left)
 3. flag which node was visited
 4. store node's index or key in an array
```